# Windows 7: Where (file/folder) is the static IP stored?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7

Like Linux, is the static IP on a windows 7 machine stored somewhere? Or the Registry?

Thanks.

Comment: Good question but off topic here. Better fit for super user?

Comment: http://www.windowsreference.com/networking/dhcp-static-ip-settings-in-windows-registry/ should be the same for windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're stored in the registry.

http://www.windowsreference.com/networking/dhcp-static-ip-settings-in-windows-registry/

Edit: I see @QuickSort beat me to it.